# How do I test whether a certain XML node exists?

Tags: xml, delphi

What is the proper way to test for the existance of an optional node?  A snipped of my XML is:

```
<Antenna >
  <Mount Model="text" Manufacture="text">
   <BirdBathMount/>
  </Mount>
</Antenna>
```

But it could also be:

```
<Antenna >
  <Mount Model="text" Manufacture="text">
   <AzEl/>
  </Mount>
</Antenna>
```

The child of Antenna could either be BirdBath or AzEl but not both...

In Delphi XE I have tried:

```
 if (MountNode.ChildNodes.Nodes['AzEl'] <> unassigned then //Does not work
 if (MountNode.ChildNodes['BirdBathMount'].NodeValue <> null) then // Does not work
 if (MountNode.BirdBathMount.NodeValue <> null) then  // Does not work
```

I use XMLSpy to create the schema and the example XML and they parse correctly.  I use Delphi XE to create the bindings and it works on most other combinations fine.

This *must* have a simple answer that I have just overlooked - but what?
Thanks...... Jim

Comment: Have you tried "VarIsNull()" from unit "Variants"?

Answer (score 9):

You can use XPath, try this sample.

```
uses
  MSXML;


Var
  XMLDOMDocument  : IXMLDOMDocument;
  XMLDOMNode      : IXMLDOMNode;
begin
  XMLDOMDocument:=CoDOMDocument.Create;
  XMLDOMDocument.loadXML(XmlStr);
  XMLDOMNode := XMLDOMDocument.selectSingleNode('//Antenna/Mount/BirdBathMount');
  if XMLDOMNode<>nil then
    Writeln('BirdBathMount node Exist')
  else
  begin
    XMLDOMNode := XMLDOMDocument.selectSingleNode('//Antenna/Mount/AzEl');
    if XMLDOMNode<>nil then
      Writeln('AzEl node Exist');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: +1 for XPath.  Since the document already would exist in any real world test, the above code sample could really be the  `selectSingleNode` call.

Comment: Note that this is Microsoft-specific. You can use XPath with `TXMLDocument/IXMLDocument` if the `DOMVendor` is set to MSXML (the default on Windows).

Comment: YOU ARE RIGHT.!!! In The Question I overlooked "The child of Antenna could either be BirdBath or AzEl but not both..." . Is It OK for you,if I delete my comments ??

Answer (score 8):

Use .FindNode. It returns nil, if the node doesn't exist.

e.g.

```
xmlNode := MountNode.ChildNodes.FindNode('AzEl');
if Assigned(xmlNode) then
...
```

Comment: This is the one that finally worked for me. {code} if (MountNode.ChildNodes.FindNode('AzEl') <> nil) then
{code}

Comment: In My example. BNode == MountNode

Answer (score 1):

I have tested it successfully. with this code. It is somewhat more complicated and I need a root element .

**XmlFile**

```
<ThisIsTheDocumentElement>
<Antenna >
  <Mount Model="text" Manufacture="text">
   <BirdBathMount/>
  </Mount>
</Antenna>
<Antenna >
  <Mount Model="text" Manufacture="text">
   <AzEl/>
  </Mount>
</Antenna>
</ThisIsTheDocumentElement>
```

**Delphi2010.pas**

```
procedure TForm1.RetrieveDocument;
var
  LDocument: IXMLDocument;
  LNodeElement, LNode,BNode,CNode : IXMLNode;
  I: Integer;
begin
  LDocument := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
  LDocument.LoadFromFile(XmlFile);
  LNodeElement := LDocument.ChildNodes.FindNode('ThisIsTheDocumentElement');
  if (LNodeElement <> nil) then
  begin
    for I := 0 to LNodeElement.ChildNodes.Count - 1 do
    begin
      LNode := LNodeElement.ChildNodes.Get(I);
       if (LNode <> Nil) AND (LNode.NodeName='Antenna') then begin
          Memo1.lines.Add('Node name: ' + LNode.NodeName);
          BNode:=LNode.ChildNodes.FindNode('Mount');
         if (BNode <> Nil) then CNode:=BNode.ChildNodes.FindNode('AzEl');
            if (CNode <> Nil) then Memo1.lines.Add('found: '+CNode.NodeName) else continue;
       end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Node name: Antenna
Node name: Antenna
found: AzEl
```

Comment: What worked for me was:'code'if (MountNode.ChildNodes.FindNode('AzEl') <> nil) then
'code'

Comment: In My example. BNode == MountNode

Comment: @moskito-x the XPath sentences `//Antenna/Mount/BirdBathMount` and `//Antenna/Mount/AzEl`  works with the xml posted by the OP, maybe you are trying with another xml.

Comment: @RRUZ I've tried it with a TMemo. The file "XMLFile.xml" (from my answer) loaded with load file and the String "xmlstr" xmlstr:= Memo1.Text; passed. With and without "<ThisIsTheDocumentElement>
"

Comment: @moskito-x, try with the XML posted by the OP, if yuu want try with you xml version try using `//ThisIsTheDocumentElement/Antenna/Mount/BirdBathMount` instead

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was:

```
if (MountNode.ChildNodes.FindNode('AzEl') <> nil) then
```

Its not clear to me how the `nil` responds to the options setting on TXMLDocumnet like `doAttrNull` but it works.